# bagof only gives one item, though multiple items fit

Tags: prolog

This code works as expected:

```
 ?- bagof(R,member(r(R),[r(a),r(b),r(c),r(d)]),Rs).
Rs = [a, b, c, d].
```

but a similar call, the one I really want, does not:

```
?- bagof(R,member(r(_,R),[r(_,a), r(_,b), r(_,c), r(_,d)]),Rs).
Rs = [a]
```

`;` gives me more answers -- but I want `[a,b,c,d]`.  What's my fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to existentially qualify the arguments that you're not interested in instead of using anonymous variables:

```
?- bagof(R,A^A1^A2^A3^A4^member(r(A,R),[r(A1,a), r(A2,b), r(A3,c), r(A4,d)]),Rs).
Rs = [a, b, c, d].
```

This is necessary as `bagof/3` (and `setof/3`) will return a bag (set) of solutions for each instantiation of the free variables (i.e. the variables in the goal that are not in the template). In alternative, you can use the `findall/3` predicate (which ignores free variables):

```
?- findall(R,member(r(A,R),[r(A1,a), r(A2,b), r(A3,c), r(A4,d)]),Rs).
Rs = [a, b, c, d].
```

But note that `findall/3` returns an empty list when there are no solutions while `bagof/3` (and `setof/3`) fail when there are no solutions.

Another alternative to avoid a long list of existentially qualified variables in calls to `bagof/3` and `setof/3` is to introduce an auxiliary predicate with a single clause whose head only lists the arguments you're interested in. For example:

```
r(R) :-
    member(r(_,R),[r(_,a), r(_,b), r(_,c), r(_,d)]).

?- bagof(R, r(R), Rs).
Rs = [a, b, c, d].
```

Comment: I think so too!  More on findall/3 v. bagof/3 here:  http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3 .  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`bagof/3` and `_` do not flock together directly. Same is true for `setof/3`.

So either give all those anonymous variables a name and declare them as a local variable, use an auxiliary predicate, or use [`library(lambda)`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord#setof):

```
?- bagof(R,R+\member(r(_,R),[r(_,a), r(_,b), r(_,c), r(_,d)]),Rs).
   Rs = [a,b,c,d].
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't work in my interpreter -- which is SWI-PROLOG, if that makes a difference.  ?

Comment: You need to install [the corresponding pack](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda).

Answer (score 1):

Paulo contributed library([yall](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)), autoloaded in SWI-Prolog. Yall (Yet Another Lambda Library) solves your problem easily:

```
?- bagof(R, {R}/member(r(_,R),[r(_,a), r(_,b), r(_,c), r(_,d)]),Rs).
Rs = [a, b, c, d].
```